# Notepad++ NppFTP authenticated, no error, no files, no folders

Tags: notepad++, sftp

NppFTP is hanging when connecting without an error message.

On starting Notepad++, `NppFTP - Disconnected`, is displayed (correctly) in the NppFTP window.

Selecting the `(Dis)connect` button and a profile starts connecting normally.

In the NppFTP - Output window the following is displayed:

```
[NppFTP] Everything initialized  
Connecting  
[SFTP] Host key accepted  
[SFTP] Banner: ~~~~  
[SFTP] Successfully authenticated
```

Everything stops here.  Normally the rest of the NppFTP buttons "light up" after connecting and files and folders can be browsed.  Only the `settings` and `show messages` buttons work.  The the NppFTP window says `NppFTP - Connecting`.

Notepad++ continues to work at this point but NppFTP is stuck.  Notepad++ must be restarted to put NppFTP back in the `Disconnected` state to enable the `(Dis)connect button`.

I'm using private key file authentication with a passphrase.  It's worked before but not now.  Ideas?

Notepad++    v6.1.5
NppFTP        v0.2.4

Comment: what have you changed on the server? In `sshd_config`, in `.bashrc`?

Comment: @Jakuje you called it.  Believe it or not an `echo 'some value'` in .bashrc will let you ssh in just fine, will run without errors, but when using NppFTP it's enough to bring the show to a screeching _(well silent really)_ halt.  Thanks.  Express this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: No problem. Common mistake :) I will write up more verbose answer below.

Comment: @Jakuje Not common enough or NppFTP would have fixed it or at least made it easier to diagnose. I can hear the author now: "why the hell would anyone echo from .bashrc?"  I was playing around.  So sue me.

Comment: It is problem of all non-interactive shells. If you write something there, you break the protocol. Unfortunately the tools don't report the errors well. We solve such problems from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put some output into your `.bashrc`. It makes your `ssh` sessions work Just fine<sup>TM</sup>, but it makes SFTP sessions fail.

If you want to have some output after login, you should limit it only to interactive sessions like this (as proposed in question on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/146745/how-can-i-check-in-bash-if-a-shell-is-running-in-interactive-mode)):

```
if [[ $- == *i* ]]; then
   echo "your stuff"
fi
```

From `man bash`:

> An interactive shell is one started without non-option arguments and without the `-c` option whose standard input and error are both connected to terminals (as determined by `isatty(3)`), or one started with the `-i` option.
> **PS1 is set and `$-` includes `i` if bash is interactive, allowing a shell script or a startup file to test this state.**

Comment: Works a treat.  Thanks bunches.  Any other .bashrc gotchas I should be wary of as I play around?